# cordova windows Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets

Tags: android, cordova

cordova not working

> windows 7

envronment path

```
D:\android\ant\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\beta\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plugman\node_modules\npm;D:\android;D:\android\sdk\tools;D:\android\sdk\platform-tools
```

C:\Users\beta\Baz>java  -version
java version "1.7.0_07"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

> C:\Users\beta\Baz>ant -version Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled
>   on December 23 2013

```
C:\Users\beta\Baz>cordova platform add android
Creating android project...

C:\Users\beta\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: An error occurred while listing Android targets
    at C:\Users\beta\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js:87
:29
    at _rejected (C:\Users\beta\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modu
les\q\q.js:808:24)
    at C:\Users\beta\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:
834:30
    at Promise.when (C:\Users\beta\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_m
odules\q\q.js:1079:31)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\beta\.cordova\lib\android\cordo
va\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:752:41)
    at C:\Users\beta\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.js:
574:44
    at flush (C:\Users\beta\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\
q\q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
Error: C:\Users\beta\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\create.bat: Command
failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\beta\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cor
dova\src\superspawn.js:126:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

C:\Users\beta\Baz>

Comment: Can't see jdkxxx\bin in the path.

Comment: Also in my case, when everything was set up, simply re-opening cmd/shell helped.

Comment: i did restart also, but worked for me. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same problem, all you need is to make sure your global PATH is set for reference see  [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html).

Make sure you restart your PC after adding those paths.
And if problem persist, that is most probably because you dont have [latest android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Add (path to ADT)\sdk\tools to your PATH environment variable

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a few days, tried everything else and the only thing that worked for me was to add the following to my PATH environment variable:
`%SYSTEMROOT%\system32;%SYSTEMROOT%;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`

My only guess as to what's up is that these are normally present in the Windows path var, and they got removed at some point in the past.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is useful for someone, I also got the same problem and it took me one day troubleshoot this.

My root cause is not related to path issue but I had created an android.bat in the same directory I run the command 'cordova platform add android'

I endup renamed android.bat that I created and problems solved.